# How can I link the current time in the audio context to input type=range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, web-audio-api

I'm using React.js and the web audio API to create an app that plays music.
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kepler-jlr05?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Could you please tell me how to link the input type=range to the music being played?
And by moving input type=range, I want to change the current time of the music being played.

---

The source code is as follows.

```js
let audioCtx, audioBuffer, source;
const audioURL = "/piano.mp3";

const App = () => {
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(true);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const audioLoad = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(audioURL);
    const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    if (arrayBuffer) {
      audioBuffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
      setTotal(audioBuffer.duration);
    }
    setLoad(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    audioLoad();
    return () => {
      audioCtx.close();
      audioCtx = null;
    };
  }, []);

  const playAudio = () => {
    if (!playing) {
      source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = audioBuffer;
      source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      source.start();
      setPlaying(true);
      return;
    }
    source.stop();
    setCurrent(0);
    setPlaying(false);
  };

  const changeSeek = (e) => {
    setCurrent(e.target.value);
    audioCtx.currentTime = current;
    console.log(audioCtx.currentTime);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>Total time {total}</p>
      <p>Current time {current}</p>
      <button onClick={playAudio} disabled={load ? true : false}>
        {playing ? "stop" : "play"}
      </button>
      <input
        onChange={changeSeek}
        value={current}
        type="range"
        max={total}
        style={inputStyle}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

The audio context has a currentTime property, and I thought I could change the current time of the music by assigning the value of input type=range to this property, but I was unable to do so.

Also, I couldn't figure out how to automatically move input type=range to match the current time of the music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseAudioContext.currentTime` is immutable.  It represents the HW audio clock so you can't just arbitrarily set to to move things around in time.  If you want to be able to seek through an `AudioBuffer`, you'll have implement the seeking there, by creating an `AudioBufferSourcNode` with the desired `AudioBuffer`, and calling `start(startTime, offset, duration)` appropriately (possibly leaving off the `duration` parameter).

Or use a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` with the `src` set up appropriately since a `MediaElement` supports seeking.  This won't be sample accurate, but perhaps that's ok for your use case.